# Would Google accept a text sitemap if the URL had a .php extension?

Tags: google, url, googlebot, sitemap, file-extension

Google accepts a sitemap as .txt file with a list of URLs separated each by a newline.

Would Google also allow the same text file format with a `.php`?  Ie.`mysitemap.php` instead of `mysitemap.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sitemap is being submitted in txt format, then it must have a .txt file extension.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

[image: Google instructions on txt sitemaps]